# Not receiving any change Notifications for MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have created 2 subscriptions (teams/allMessages and chats/allMessages) and both have correct notification endpoint (received validation and acknowledged it). I am not receiving any notification if a message was sent on teams. Is there a page to know if the request is enqueued but not delivered or if there is an outage which is causing a delay for receiving the change notification. How do we usually debug such an issue?

```
Subscription registration:
{
    "changeType": "created,updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://...amazonaws.com/api/notification/teams",
    "resource": "chats/allMessages",
    "clientState": "12c189af-16ed-41f9-9742-7c9f0fa2e22e",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-07-16T22:01:33.639215Z",
    "includeResourceData": true,
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "...",
    "encryptionCertificateId": "84474ac9-eb09-41c3-b83e-396ffdc96a22",
    "encryptionCertificate": "..."
}
```

Comment: Did you get your application added to the allowlist for `chats/allMessages` and `teams/allMessages` ?

Comment: Yes I have permission for protected APIs and it was working fine until yesterday morning. It is working again today. Thanks for looking though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service had a temporary issue and notifications got delayed for a couple of hours. Whenever this sort of issue happens you should open a support ticket to get the issue investigated.